# How to display joined table in java?

Tags: java, mysql

i am new to java and i need help about how to display joined table/query in jtable.

First , i have done displaying data from 1 table which is :
- Select data from 1 table
- insert the result to its entity and insert each one of it to a List
- return the list to view and insert row to jtable

( i am using DAO pattern , which have factory, interface, implement, entity and view )

So what if i select data from other table ?

here is my get method in implement for getting book

```
 public List get(String find) {
    try {
        ps = db.connect().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title like ? ");
        ps.setString(1, "%" + find + "%");

        status = db.execute(ps);
        if (status) {
            books = db.get_result();
            listBooks = new ArrayList<>();

            while (books.next()) {
                entity_books b = new entity_books();
                b.setId(books.getInt(1));
                b.setId_category(books.getInt(2)); 
                b.setTitle(books.getString(3));
                listBooks.add(b);
            }
            books.close();
            return listBooks;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then in my view :

```
listBooks = booksDAO.get(find.getText());
    model = (DefaultTableModel) book_table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);

    listBooks.forEach((data) -> {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
            data.getId(),
            data.getId_category(),
            data.getTitle(),

        });
    });
```

it works fine , but i want the query to join table so i can see the category name instead of just ID category. i can do the query , but how do i apply that to my code ?

Hope you can help , Thanks !

UPDATE
here is the query for joined table

```
select title,category from book b
join category c on c.id = b.id_category
```

Normally if i select only 1 table i would insert it to its entity ( book table -> book entity ) , so how do i handle this multi table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Re-write the SQL-Statement to be already the desired join. This has nothing to do with java. It is basic SQL knowhow. Try your SQL-Statements which you want to use in java first by an external tool (e.g. MySqlWorkbench if you are working with MySql) before you write the java code based on the result set.

Without knowing your table structure and the used foreign key between the two tables I cannot help more.

Comment: i am sorry for not including the joined query ." select title,category from book b join category c on c.id = b.id_category" here it will result in "book title & category name" and then i stuck there because normally i would insert the book result to book entity